# Excel Macro to get by Security PopUp

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to log into a website but I keep getting stopped by a security alert pop up that requires me to click OK to continue.  Any idea what lines to put in to make it click on the OK button so I can proceed to the site?

Comment: whether you are getting the security pop up in browser? If so it can be disabled by Security Settings in browser. By setting disabled option for "Launching application and Safe files". For reference http://wiki.imacros.net/Disable_Secure_and_NonSecure_Items_Warning_Message

Comment: @Nagappan unfortunately it is for my work computer and hey don't give me permissions to reset the security settings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with VBA, a few options come to mind. The quick and dirty approach would just be to use Sendkeys, and send Enter. It's super unreliable though, but may work in your specific case.

Another option is using windows APIs to send/post the relevant message to the window. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011252/findwindow-and-sendmessage)

The final option I'll offer is considering Authotkey as a language stand-in. It makes this type of interaction really easy. It has COM support, so you can still use Excel, just like VBA.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.contextures.com/excelvbasendkeys.html

SendKeys should be able to do this I think...

```
SendKeys "~"
```

O

Comment: It is customary to bring the relevant code from a link into your post as the link might die in the future.